# echo does not work, but the table is successfully updated

Tags: php, echo, undefined-index

When updating my table, it works fine. but the only problem is that i **can't seem to echo the fields in the input.**
and showing the error, undefined index. i don't get it, i tried everything. but it won't echo.

For instance:

Undefined index: fam_name in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/finalproject/admin/records/activities_update.php on line 80

i have no problem in getting the ID echoed. but the other variables fam_name , fam_add, nochild, aid and so on... i can't retrieve it. i hope you understand what i'm trying to say

i tried using $_POST , $_GET and rows, doesn;t work =\

need help been trying to solve this for days.

```
 <?php 
if(isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true){
    echo ' Your details have been updated';
} else {

if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
    $fam_data = array(
            'fam_name'                  => $_POST['fam_name'],
            'fam_add'                   => $_POST['fam_add'],
            'nochild'                   => $_POST['nochild'],
            'aid'                       => $_POST['aid'],
            'date_visited'              => $_POST['date_visited'],
            'visited_since'                 =>  $_POST['visited_since'],
            );

        edit_family($fam_data);
        header('Location: rec_act1.php?success');
        exit();
        //exit();

} else if (empty($errors) === false) {
    echo output_errors($errors);
}

?>

<div id="insert_form">
<form name="update" action = "" method ="post">
<table border = "0" align = "center">
<tr> 
    <th colspan = "2"> </th>
</tr>
<tr>

    <td><input type = "hidden" name = "id" maxlength = "9" value="<?php echo $id = $_GET['id'];?>"></td> Editing: <?php echo $id = $_GET['id'];?>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Family Name: </td>
    <td><input type = "text" name = "fam_name" maxlength = "9"  value="<?php echo $_POST['fam_name']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>No. Of Family: </td>
    <td><input type = "text" name = "nochild" maxlength = "30"  value="<?php echo $row['nochild'];?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Family Address: </td>
    <td><input type = "text" name = "fam_add" maxlength = "30"  value="<?php echo $row['fam_add'];?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Types of Aid received: </td>
    <td><input type = "float" name = "aid" step = 'any' min = 1 max = 99999999  value="<?php echo $row['aid'];?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Date Visited</td>
    <td><input type = "date" name = "date_visited"  value="<?php echo $row['date_visited'];?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Visited Since </td>
    <td><input type = "date" name = "visited_since" value="<?php echo $row['visited_since'];?>"></td>
</tr>


    <td><input type ="submit" name = "submit" value = "Update"></td></table>
</form></div><? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For get data in `$_GET` you need to send all of your variables in query string like

```
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
   $fam_name = $_POST['fam_name'];
   // set your all vars

    <------rest of code ---->

   header('Location: rec_act1.php?id=$id&fam_name=$fam_name');
```

and get your query string var in value like:-

```
value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>"
value="<?php echo $_GET['fam_name'];?>"
// and so on
```

Comment: nahh i don't think that's the problem =\ i meant to say the echo fields in the input. it won't echo.

Comment: have you tried to send in query strings your all vars

Answer (score 0):

`$row` used in form doesn't exists.

Before form you need to select current data from table, than saved that data to `$row`.

```
$row = $mysqli->fetch_assoc($mysqli->query($conn, "SELECT ...")); // select family data
```

In $mysqli is MySQLi instance, of course.

Due to updating row I expect you have data in your database. If you don't know, and don't want to see `undefined index` notices, in form values has to be an `isset`, eg.

```
value="<? echo isset($row['fam_name']) ? $row['fam_name'] : ''; ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing here as it's not clear where you're using echo, but I am guessing the data is lost after the header redirect as the information most certainly won't be available in rec_act1.php. Try rewriting the script to not redirect, or if you must, pass along the data in a session.

Answer (score 0):

Do not echo `$_POST` variables directly, it allows for the possibility of XSS attacks, always sanitize first. I also notice in your code, that you are creating the `$fam_data` array and directly afterward redirecting without creating a `$_SESSION` so the array is going to be lost unless your edit_family function starts a session. The issue to me, seems to be that you are not receiving your `$_POST['fam_name']` variable from the form or it is lost on page refresh.

Try adding...

```
//start session before any output to browser
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['fam_name'])) {
    //only process the request if expected values are found
    if (ctype_alpha($_POST['fam_name'])) {
        $_SESSION['fam_name'] = $_POST['fam_name'];
    }
} else {
    //this alert will let you know if the value was empty
    echo "no family name received";
    exit;
}
```

Then in your form input, use...

```
value="<?php echo $_SESSION['fam_name']; ?>">
```